# How to find all substrings in a string that starts with {{ and ends with }

Tags: python

How to find all substrings in a string that looks like this one `{{ test_variable }`?

```
s = "hi {{ user }}, samle text, {{ test_variable } 2100210121, testing"
```

My try:

`finds = re.findall(r"(\{{ .*?\}$)", s)`

but this regex return also substring that ends with `}}` instead of only `}` so I see unwanted `{{ user }}` in result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the following regex pattern:

```
\{\{\s*([^{} ]+)\s*\}(?=[^}]|$)
```

This is similar to what you are using, but it makes use of a positive lookahead after the closing `}` to ensure that what follows is either not another `}`, or is the end of the string.

```
\{\{\s*([^{} ]+)\s*\}   match desired string as {{ STRING }
(?=[^}]|$)              then assert that what follows the final } is NOT
                        another }, or is the end of the entire string
```

Script:

```
s = "hi {{ user }}, samle text, {{ test_variable } 2100210121, testing"
matches = re.findall(r'{{\s*([^{} ]+)\s*}(?=[^}]|$)', s)
print(matches)

['test_variable']
```

Comment: I'm curious @Tim — do you need these escapes in a raw string: `\{\{`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer No, you don't, but it might be a good idea to do so anyway.  In any case, to get the regex to work on a test tool, you'd still probably have to escape them.